# How to minimize this non-linear function?

Tags: optimization, minimization

minimize the following function:

[image]

subject to inequality constraints:

[image]

S1(v) and S2(v) are the observations. t, r(v) and p(v) are the unknowns (v=1,...,n). I have very good initial values for r(v) and p(v). My question is: how to estimate t, r(v) and p(v)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking this question here and not on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com), I assume you're asking about numerically optimizing it with some programming language.

Since you have a highly non-linear problem here, you could, e.g., use the [fminsearch()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) function in Matlab. Alternatively, you could have a look at Numerical Recipies that describe how to implement various numerical algorithms in C++.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I need to move my question to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [OPTIF9](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/docs/cmlib/uncmin/optif9) for optimizing nonlinear functions, and there is a variation on it that handles [constraints on the parameters](http://www3.nd.edu/~jstiver/FIN510/Constrained%20Optimization.pdf).
It's tricky, because whenever it comes up against a boundary, that reduces the dimensionality of the problem by 1.
Another approach is to transform the parameters by a function, such as log or logit, that implicitly is bounded.

Personally, I prefer Metropolis-Hastings. It's simple, and you can just put in a big penalty for out-of-bounds parameters.
Since you're minimizing a sum of squares, with equal weighting for all observations, it's trivial to consider it a case of maximizing a gaussian log-likelihood, and MH is good at that.